# Silverlight ContentControl in ItemTemplate

Tags: silverlight, data-binding

I`m trying to figure out why this code

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestSilverlight.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

<UserControl.Resources>
    <Button x:Key="button" Content="{Binding}" />
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Yellow">
    <ListBox Name="listBox">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource button}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TestSilverlight
{
    public partial class MainPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            listBox.ItemsSource = new List<string> {"a", "b", "c"}; //without this line it works
        }
    }
}
```

doesnt work. It throws Parser Exception (can`t set property Content in ContentControl). Without binding it works perfectly. Is it ok?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is something wrong with your logic. If you define a resource of type Button - that makes one instance of a button. You can't have a single instance of a control be a content of multiple controls.

Why not just do this:

```
<ListBox Name="listBox">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: It plays no role. This example is the small part of code i want to make work. I didn`t bind button content to show that even in that case it doesn`t work. The only thing i need is content to be in resourses (or somewhere else exept inside template tag). I wish to set a part of item template (NOT THE WHOLE TEMPLATE, in this case i could use template selector).

Comment: I forgot to say that my question is why exactly THIS code doesn`t work.

Comment: Could have something to do with name scopes perhaps. Maybe try putting the resource in app.xaml

Comment: I notice that the same code works well in wpf application. It seems to me that it is silverlight`s bug.